# How does this electromagnet control circuit work?

Tags: diodes, reverse-engineering, electromagnet

I am reverse engineering an electromagnet control circuit in isolation (I do not have the original controls or wiring diagram).  I believe applying 12VDC should trigger the respective magnets, but it does not, so I am trying to understand this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxjeAn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Background:

- R1 looks to be 4-stripe, orange, white, black, silver, which I decoded to 39 ohms.
- I can't make out the diode labels well; I diagrammed only digits that I could clearly read.

**Question 1:** Is the point of D1 and D2 reverse current protection?  My understanding is that they ensure that the magnets only operate when B is positive and A and/or C are negative.

**Question 2:** What is the point of D3 and D4?

**Question 3-5:** How can I know if this is intended for 12V?  Does the size of R1 give a clue?  Have I decoded it correctly?

Here is a picture of the circuit (mostly to check my resistor decoding).  Notes:

- I cut one end of the resistor to examine the circuit.  I have dozens of this identical circuit.
- There is a switch in the circuit which is isolated and not part of the diagram (the horizontal and rightmost vertical terminals).

[image]

Thank you for helping a novice.

Comment: Diodes are probably 1N4004

Answer (score 3, accepted):

B = 12V. Connect A or C to gnd to power the corresponding coil.

D3 and D4 are flyback diodes.

The coils have a current rating. R1 can be sized so that you can use any voltage higher than the minimum voltage required to drive the desired current through the coils if the resistor weren't there,

D1 and D2 don't seem strictly necessary.

Comment: Looks to me like B is common/positive, and Ground/negative to A or C to power the correspoonding coil.

Comment: @PeterBennett yeah. typo

Comment: I think you meant B = 12V

Comment: I kept trying different boards and finally one worked.  I don't know what has caused the others to fail, but indeed +12V at B and negative to A or C operates the coils.